# Multi-thread build with Apache Ant

Tags: multithreading, makefile, ant

How can I initiate a build process with Apache Ant that
is executed in parallel on multiple threads? That is, 
I am searching for that corresponds to '-j' in GNU Make.

Comment: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/parallel.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute an Ant build target that has the **parallel** task. ([see docs here](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/parallel.html))

Assuming you have a macro called 'dbpurge' that takes a 'file' argument. The following example would describe running 40 calls to dbpurge with a thread count (jobs count in GNU Make) of '4'.

```
<parallel threadCount="4">
  <dbpurge file="db/one" />
  <dbpurge file="db/two" />
  <dbpurge file="db/three" />
  <dbpurge file="db/four" />
  <dbpurge file="db/five" />
  <dbpurge file="db/six" />
  <dbpurge file="db/seven" />
  <dbpurge file="db/eight" />
  <!-- repeated about 40 times -->
</parallel>
```